# Updating value in DOM from Javascript with Ember.js

Tags: binding, view, ember.js

I am new to Ember.js.  I have the following experiment in my HTML:

```
<p>Username: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="MyApp.loginController.bound.username" id="view-login-username" placeholder="Your username"}}</p>

The username field is: {{MyApp.loginController.bound.username}}

{{#view Ember.Button
     classBinding="isActive"
     target="MyApp.loginController"
     action="submitLogin"}}
     Login {{/view}}
```

And I have the following in my Javascript:

```
MyApp = SC.Application.create();
MyApp.loginController = Ember.Object.create({
    bound : { username:'12345' },

    submitLogin: function() {
        MyApp.loginController.bound.username = "abcdef";
        alert(MyApp.loginController.bound.username);
    }
});
```

When I push my 'login' button, the change to "abcdef" does not appear in the DOM nor in the alert() immediately following the assignment.  The alert appears but still displays "12345".

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should probably be put in 120pt font at the top of the Ember homepage:

**When using properties on Ember objects, ALWAYS use Ember's universal accessors (get, getPath, set, and setPath)!**

Change `MyApp.loginController.bound.username = "abcdef";` to `MyApp.loginController.setPath('bound.username', "abcdef");`

Comment: Perfect.  I actually tried set() too, but that didn't work.  setPath() it is, then!  Thank you!

Comment: get/set are for properties on the current object. Use getPath/setPath when you need a property that is nested.